# Error while writing author name in IEEEtran

Tags: ieeetran

I tried this code to write title and and author name for my work in IEEE template, but I am geting this warning

> Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
>
> \end@IEEEauthorhalign ->\crcr \egroup \egroup
> l.61 \maketitle
> I've deleted a group-closing symbol because it seems to be spurious, as in `$x}$'. But perhaps the } is legitimate and you forgot something else, as in` \hbox{$x}'. In such cases the way to
> recover is to insert both the forgotten and the deleted material,
> e.g., by typing `I$}'.

```
\title{MY PAPERRRRR\\

%\thanks{Identify applicable funding agency here. If none, delete this.}
}

\author{\IEEEauthorblockN{AUTHOR1\IEEEauthorrefmark{1},
AUTHOR2\IEEEauthorrefmark{2}, AUTHOR3\IEEEauthorrefmark{3}}
\IEEEauthorblockA \textit{{Department }\\
\textit{universiy name}\\
\textit{university}\\
{city,country}}\\
Email: {\IEEEauthorrefmark{1}a@.net,
\IEEEauthorrefmark{2}b@.net,
\IEEEauthorrefmark{3}a@.net}}
\maketitle
```

Comment: This code snippet does not produce any errors if it is made into a MWE with `\documentclass{IEEEtran}\begin{document}...\end{document}`. If you're still seeing errors, you'll have to update your code snippet, so that it's a complete document that we can compile and inspect the errors.

Comment: You keep asking questions that are difficult to answer because of the lack of information. Please have a look at https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that.